# How to share guest (Ubuntu) internet with host (MacOS) using vmware?

Tags: networking, macos, vmware-fusion, gateway

My new usb-wifi dongle only properly works with Linux. I successfully set it up in my Ubuntu vmware-vm and shared the vm's internet connection. I checked that by connecting to the internet from another guest machine (Win7) by setting its gateway to the Ubunut vm's ip. Both vms are configured as host-only within a shared subnet.

However, I cannot get my MacOS host to use this internet connection. The vmnet1 network interface does not seem to have a gateway property.

How can I set the MacOS gateway to the Ubuntu vm?

Answer (score 0):

Can you get it working in Bridged mode? In the past I have tried to setup host only networks and gave up and just used bridged.